# Attempt to de-reference a null object in apex class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am getting the following error:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Stack Trace: Class.unsubscribe_user.unsubscribeMe: line 21, column 1
>   Class.unsubscribe_test.unsubscribe_test: line 29, column 1

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Apex Test:**

```
@isTest
private class unsubscribe_test {

    static testMethod void unsubscribe_test() {

        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name =  'TestAccount';
        acc.Airport__c = 'LHR';
        acc.Industry = 'Airline';
        acc.LHR__c = true;
        acc.AcctExtID__c = '123';
        acc.Customer_Account_number__c = '112233';
        acc.Compare_Customer_Accont_Number__c=112233;
        insert acc;

        Contact co = new Contact();
        co.AccountId = acc.Id;
        co.Email = 'johndoe_test@mail.com';
        co.LastName = 'CONTACT';
        co.Airport__c = 'LHR';
        insert co;

        PageReference pg = Page.Unsubscribe;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pg);

        unsubscribe_user controller = new unsubscribe_user();
        // Act
        controller.email = co.Email;
        controller.unsubscribeMe();

        // Assert
        Contact insertedData = [SELECT Id, Email, HasOptedOutOfEmail FROM Contact WHERE Email = :co.Email];
        System.assertEquals(insertedData.hasOptedOutOfEmail, true);

    }

}
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
public class unsubscribe_user {
    public String email {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String token {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public unsubscribe_user() {}

    public PageReference unsubscribeMe() {
        try {
            List<Contact> contactList = [
                select Name,
                    Email,
                    HasOptedOutOfEmail
                from Contact
                where Email = :email and
                    Id = :token.substring(10) and
                    hasOptedOutOfEmail = false
                limit 100
            ];

            if (contactList.isEmpty()) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning, 'You are not in our mailing list (you may have already been removed)'));
                return null;
            }

            for (Contact contact: contactList) {
                contact.hasOptedOutOfEmail = true;
            }    

            update contactList;
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, 'You have been successfully removed from our mailing list'));
        } catch (System.QueryException e) {
            System.debug(System.LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Contact Query Issue: ' + e.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Fatal, 'FATAL Error: Please contact the administrator'));
        }   

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't tell you what you are doing wrong without seeing the code from `unsubscribe_user.unsubscribeMe` but the error message is saying that line 21 of the `unsubscribe_user` class has a NullPointerException. The second line number (29) in the error is referring to the line in your test that called the method the error happened in.

Comment: My appologies, I forgot to add the controller. I have updated the post.

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe Ah of course! Please convert into the answer.

Comment: Converted into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting any value for the property `token` after you instantiate your controller

```
unsubscribe_user controller = new unsubscribe_user();
// Act
controller.email = co.Email;
controller.token = 'Your value here';
```